# ValueError at /createuser/ invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'satya'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users, django-errors

i am trying to create user . first i am checking if user exists or not but for first time it gives me this error:

> ValueError at /createuser/
>
> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'satya'

and when i refresh this page works fine.
my code:

```
for i in range(0, len(username)):
        try:
            print(username[i])
            user = User.objects.get(username = username[i])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username[i], email=email[i], password=password[i],first_name=firstname[i],last_name=lastname[i] )
            group.user_set.add(username[i])
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do

```
group.user_set.add(user.id)
```